# How Gelfond find his limit for $\exp(\pi) $?

Tags: limits, roots, fixed-point-theorems, pi

$$ a_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} $$

$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{( \sqrt {1 - a_n^2} -1)^2}{a_n^2} $$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}{a_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{2^n}}} = \exp(\pi) $$

How did Gelfond find this nice result ?
And how to prove it ? 
The 4 is trivial , but the rest is not.
Is this related to trigonometry ?
Is this related to continued fractions ?

Are there analogues known for cube roots ?

Notice a proof alone might not explain how he found the result.

Comment: mick  Please check my edits, fairly minor, but primarily check those for the for $a_{n+1}$.  It seemed as though you intended for the square root to extend over all of  $1 -a_n^2$.

Comment: Yes I did amwhy.

Comment: The theory behind the result is difficult and you may get a brief explanation from my answer to the original question. The details would require some study of elliptic integrals and theta functions which are covered nicely in my blog.

Comment: Also Gelfond did not find this result. Rather the constant $e^\pi$ goes by the name Gelfond's constant.

Comment: A similar iteration can be given using same approach involving cube roots (or nth roots in general) but the iteration would be clumsy and hard to follow.

Answer (score 4):

This is the [Gauss-Legendre algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm) **non homogeneous** version for the [elliptic modulus k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant). That is, let
 $\, a_n = k(q_n) = (\theta_2(q_n)/\theta_3(q_n))^2 \,$ where $\, q_n = \exp(-\pi 2^n). \,$
We have $\, a_{n+1} = 4 q_n + O(q_n^3). \,$

Legendre used the following:
 $\, k_{n+1} = (1 - k'_n)/(1 + k'_n) = k_n^2/(1 + k'_n)^2 = (1 - k'_n)^2/k_n^2 \,$ where $\, 1 = k_n^2 + k_n'^2. \,$
The AGM of Gauss is
 $\, a_{n+1} \!=\! \frac12(a_n \!+\! b_n), $
 $ b_{n+1} \!=\! \sqrt{a_n b_n}, \, $
 $ c_{n+1} \!=\! \frac12(a_n\!-\!b_n). \,$
The connection is $\, k_n = c_n/a_n, \, k_n' = b_n/a_n. \,$
For more details, you can read the standard book *Pi and the AGM* by Borwein and Borwein.

By the way, the recursion as written
 $\, a_{n+1} = (\sqrt {1 - a_n^2} -1)^2/a_n^2, \,$
is not good from a numerical point of view. The subtraction of two numbers nearly equal causes drastic [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). The equivalent recursion
 $\, a_{n+1} = a_n^2 / (1 + \sqrt {1 - a_n^2})^2 \,$ does not suffer from significance loss.

Comment: Plz Explain more. I do not see a geometric average nor an arithmetic explicitly , I do not know What your thetas are. And are saying it is actually gauss result ? Even If it is the AGM , How was the result reached and found ? Integral representation of AGM from Gauss or What ? Thank you.